# Equivalence classes of mappings from $T^{2}$ to an arbitrary space $X$

Tags: condensed-matter, mathematical-physics, topological-order, topological-insulators, quantum-hall-effect

I was reading the paper "Homotopy and quantization in condensed matter physics", by J.E Avron et al. ( http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.51.51). There they have classified the mappings from $T^{2}$ to an arbitrary space $X$. Their argument is the following: "Think about two maps of $T^{2}$ into an arbitrary space X. If we take the two basic loops in
$T^{2}$, we obtain from each map two elements of $\pi_{1}(X)$ and the two maps cannot be homotopic unless the corresponding pair of elements of $\pi_{1}(X)$ are the same. Even if they are the same, there is clearly a leftover map from $S^{2}$ into X." In this way, one can classify maps from $T^{2}$ into X by two elements of $\pi_{1}(X)$, and one element of $\pi_{2}(X)$.

Now I understand how the two elements of $\pi_{1}(X)$ come about. But I do not understand how the elements of $\pi_{2}(X)$ come into the picture. In other words what is meant by the "leftover map from $S^{2}$ into X" ?

Answer (score 2):

Recall that homotopy groups $\pi_n(X)$ are given as homotopy classes of maps $S^n\to X$, and that every map $f : T^2\to X$ induces maps $f_* : \pi_n(T^2)\to\pi_n(X), [g]\mapsto [f\circ g]$.

Now $\pi_1(T^2) = \mathbb{Z}^2$, but $\pi_2(T^2)=0$. If two maps $f,h: T^2\to X$ are now homotopic, $f_*$ and $g_*$ must send the two generators of $\pi_1(T^2)$ to the same elements in $\pi_1(X)$. But, if $\pi_2(X)\neq 0$, this is not any condition on the map on the $\pi_2$, since they always send everything to $0$. Therefore, you could say there is a "leftover" element in $\pi_2(X)$, because the maps do not determine anything in $\pi_2(X)$, in particular, they do not give you an interesting subgroup.

If $\pi_2(X)\neq\mathbb{Z}$, then it is not clear why the authors speak of "one leftover map $S^2\to X$". I suspect the "arbitrary space" is not really arbitrary.

Comment: @ACuriousMind got it. Now if one has to classify maps of $T^{n}$ into $X$, we have to specify, $n$ elements of $\pi_{1}(X)$, $n \choose 2$ elements of $\pi_{2}(X)$, $n \choose 3$ elements of $\pi_{3}(X)$ and so on. Is that right ?

Comment: I guess in the special case when $\pi_{2}(X)$ is zero then the two elements of $\pi_{1}(X)$ completely determine the equivalence.